# Find all vertex starting from an other (two ways are possible)

Tags: orientdb

I have this template for my database:

[image]

I want to do a query that return all the "Ontologie" linked to one specific "Rubrique".

It can take all the edge except "Facultatif".

I actually have this query that return all the "Ontologie" but it doesn't pass by "Regle" so i don't have every "Ontologie"

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT expand(in('Synonyme').in('Identifie').in('Regroupe'))
  FROM Rubrique
  WHERE libelle = "collèges, lycées avec internat"
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
select expand($c)
let $a = ( SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT expand(in().in('Identifie').in('Regroupe'))
 FROM Rubrique
 WHERE libelle="collèges, lycées avec internat"
)), 
$b = ( SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT expand(in('Pertinent').out('Obligatoire'))
 FROM Rubrique
 WHERE libelle="collèges, lycées avec internat"
)), 
$c=unionAll($a,$b)
```

Hope it helps